# Error finding the the radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Determine the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ when $a_n=(\log n)^2$

I would like to apply Hadamard formula but I am having trouble computing it.

$$R=\frac{1}{\limsup|a_n|^\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{\limsup|(\log n)^2|^\frac{1}{n}}$$

however, from here I am stuck. Am I allowed to write the demoniator as $\limsup|\frac{2\log(n)}{n}|$ and apply l'hopital's rule to get $\limsup|\frac{2\frac{1}{n}}{n}|=\limsup{|\frac{2}{n^2}|}=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you be allowed to write the denominator in that form? That's not how exponents work.

To solve this what I would do is the consider taking the logarithm of $\log(n)^{2/n}$ to clear the exponent. This gives:

$$\log\left(\log(n)^{2/n}\right)=\frac{2\log\log(n)}{n}$$

Now we can consider L'Hopitals rule, as
$$\frac{d/dn(\log\log(n))}{d/dn(n)}=\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$$
which goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, therefore
$$\log\left(\log(n)^{2/n}\right)\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$, and by the continuity of $e^x$ we have that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n)^{2/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\log\left(\log(n)^{2/n}\right)\right)=e^0=1$$
Since the limit exists, it equals the $\limsup$, hence
$$\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\log(n)^2|^{1/n}}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$